# SQL pass the row or add subsequent row based on column values

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

I have s select statement that returns some rows as follows:

```
a| b| c| d|
1, 2, 5, 1
1, 5, 7, 1
2, 5, 4, 1
2, 5, 2, 2
3, 5, 9, 1
```

and what I need to happen is if col a and col b in subsequent rows match, they represent the same object and c needs to be added for the rows and returned as a single row.  it the next row doesn't match it needs to be returned.  Im not sure I need column d, it just was generated from a different select.

The results for the query would look like

```
a| b| c| d
1, 2, 5, 1
1, 5, 7, 1
2, 5, 6, 1  // the combination of rows 3 & 4
3, 5, 9, 1
```

Sorry, I think too much like a programmer.  If someone can give me a place to start I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Edit your question and show the result set.  Your explanation is pretty hard to follow.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: also *subsequent rows* is vague. you need to specify which column specifies the row order.

Comment: Does the order actually matter?  For instance, if a=2, b=5 showed up anywhere else in the result set, would you want its 'c' value added as well?  If so, just `select a, b, sum(c) from XXX group by a, b` ?

Comment: @JeffBreadner sounds like an answer to me

Comment: @all I need to rethink the problem.  I have a select that generates the rows with column d = 1 and another select that generates the rows with d = 2.  I used union to put them together and I think there has to be a better way.  Sorry to spend your time.

Comment: Yes the order matters because I eventually want to figure out how to subtract the two rows.  It is different and probably needs a different approach because subtraction is not associative.   But thats another problem.

Answer (score 1):

`select a, b, sum(c) as c from XXX group by a, b`

The shift that a programmer has to make when starting to learn SQL is to not think of the data set procedurally, you're not iterating over the data row by row.  You operate on it as a set.  It can be a difficult transition to make.

Information on aggregation:

- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp
- http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-aggregate-functions-sql-tutorial

This is pretty basic SQL, I'd suggest working through some tutorials or HackerRank kind of things to get more familiar with the language.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Group By` with `SUM` and `MIN` functions.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/844c2/4)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (a int, b int, c int, d int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (a, b, c, d)
VALUES
    (1, 2, 5, 1),
    (1, 5, 7, 1),
    (2, 5, 4, 1),
    (2, 5, 2, 2),
    (3, 5, 9, 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT a
    ,b
    ,SUM(c) AS c
    ,MIN(d) AS d
FROM t
GROUP BY a
    ,b
ORDER BY a
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/844c2/4/0)**:

```
| a | b | c | d |
|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 7 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 6 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 9 | 1 |
```